# Properly render unnumbered sections

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I have added an `\ast` before every numbered section by adding `\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\bf}{$\ast$}{.5em}{\thesection ~}`. However, it produces improper rendering for unnumbered sections. For this MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\bf}{$\ast$}{.5em}{\thesection ~}

\begin{document}

\section{something}

%\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\bf}{}{}{~}
\section*{somethig again}
%\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\bf}{$\ast$}{.5em}{\thesection ~}

\section{something once again}

\end{document}
```

I am getting:

[image]

I have also fixed this (remove the `%`'s from the code), but this process is cumbersome. For every non-real section, I need to add these two lines. What is a better way?

Comment: Not answering your question, but you should use `\bfseries` instead of `\bf`.

Comment: Does this command do what you want: `\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\bf}{$\ast$~\thesection~}{.5em}{}` ?

Comment: @ChristophB. Your solution worked, but I like cmhughes's one. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In what follows I have appended your code to include instructions for the formatting of the `\section*` command using

```
% \section*
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\Large\scshape\bfseries}
{}
{.5em}
{}
```

I have also used `\llap{$\ast$}` to make sure that the `*` doesn't take up any horizontal space.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}%
{\Large\scshape\bfseries}
{\llap{$\ast$}}
{.5em}
{\thesection ~}

% \section*
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\Large\scshape\bfseries}
{}
{.5em}
{}

\begin{document}

\section{something}
\section*{somethig again}
\section{something once again}

\end{document}
```